# SwiftUI - Change Text with fade animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'd like to see how I can make it so changes to a Text view's source change with a fade in and out.

So if I've got a simple view like the following:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var text = "I am a shrubber."
    
    func changeText() {
        text = (text == "I am a shrubber.") ? "My name is Roger the Shrubber." : "I am a shrubber."
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.text)
            TestButton(label: "Change", action: changeText)
        }
    }
    
}
```

If I tap the button the text changes instantly.

[image: Instant transition]

Now, if I wrap the changing code in a `withAnimation` block, or add an `.animation` view modifier to the Text view, it just animates the change in the frame size. Which isn't what I'm looking for:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var text = "I am a shrubber."
    
    func changeText() {
        withAnimation {
            text = (text == "I am a shrubber.") ? "My name is Roger the Shrubber." : "I am a shrubber."
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.text)
            TestButton(label: "Change", action: changeText)
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image: Frame resizing]

Of course, I could get close to the effect I'm looking for by using `.transition` view modifiers and separate text fields (this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60984127/5919644), like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var changed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if !changed {
                Text("I am a shrubber.")
                    .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration:0.3)))
            }
            if changed {
                Text("My name is Roger the Shrubber.")
                    .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration:0.3)))
            }
            
            TestButton(label: "Change", action: { self.changed.toggle() })
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image: Fading]

But that is terrible pattern and doesn't work with arbitrary text changes. And even then the fade in and out happen at the same time. I'd like to have the fade out/in happen sequentially.

Comment: have you tried using animation duration?, For example,  '.animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3))  '

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can force SwiftUI to create different Text View for each currentText by setting id and use animated transition:

```
struct TestView: View {    
    @State private var text: String = "Alpha"
    
    private var values: [String] = ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel"]
    
    private func updateText() {
        self.text = values.randomElement()!
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
                .id(text)
                .transition(.opacity.animation(.linear))

            Button("Change", action: updateText).padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so I think I've found the best way to handle this myself: watching for changes via a binding's publisher, then manually fading out, changing text, and fading back.

The view looks like this:

```
struct FadingTextView: View {
    
    @Binding var source: String
    var transitionTime: Double
    
    @State private var currentText: String? = nil
    @State private var visible: Bool = false
    private var publisher: AnyPublisher<[String.Element], Never> {
        source
            .publisher
            .collect()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    init(text: Binding<String>, totalTransitionTime: Double) {
        self._source = text
        self.transitionTime = totalTransitionTime / 3
    }
    
    private func update(_: Any) {
        guard currentText != nil else {
            currentText = source
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + (transitionTime)) {
                self.visible = true
            }
            return
        }
        guard source != currentText else { return }
        self.visible = false
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + (transitionTime)) {
            self.currentText = source
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + (transitionTime)) {
                self.visible = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(currentText ?? "")
            .opacity(visible ? 1 : 0)
            .animation(.linear(duration: transitionTime))
            .onReceive(publisher, perform: update(_:))
    }
    
}
```

Then it can be used for arbitrary text changes like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var text: String = "Alpha"
    
    private var values: [String] = ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel"]
    
    private func updateText() {
        self.text = values.randomElement()!
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FadingTextView(text: $text, totalTransitionTime: 1.0)
            Button("Change", action: updateText).padding()
        }
    }
}
```

And looks like this:

[image: Result screen recording]

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply asymmetric transition with conditional insertion delay like this:

```
struct FadeInOutView<Value: Hashable, Content: View>: View {

    let value: Value
    let content: (Value) -> Content
    
    @State private var didAppear = false

    var body: some View {
        content(value)
            .transition(.asymmetric(
                insertion: .opacity.animation(
                    .easeInOut(duration: 0.35).delay(didAppear ? 0.2 : 0)
                ),
                removal: .opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2))
            ))
            .id(value)
            .onAppear { didAppear = true }
    }
}
```

With `didAppear` condition content will appear without any delay.

But using `.id` modifier makes SwiftUI recreate internal view state every time identifier's value changes and re-render the whole view. So it becomes more performance heavy, and it's better not to use this solution on complex views.